# Best Practise for Observables used in an Angular 2 Data Service

Tags: angular, service, observable, angularfire2

I've spent the last week or so learning observables and what you can do with them, seems pretty awesome. Many tutorials and examples simply implement event based observables in a very plain and static environment. My question relates to how observables should be treated when injected via services in Angular 2.

In this example I'd like to reference the use of AnularFire2's `FirebaseObjectObservable`. Stripped down, my app is structured with a `main` component that includes an injectable `data.service.ts` that connects to my Firebase database. I have a `getData()` method on that service.

Should `getData()` return the `FirebaseObjectObservable` or should it set a property on the service called `data` which is of type FirebaseObjectObservable, thus allowing other components of my app to subscribe to `dataService.data` rather than calling `getData()` again, which presumably makes another data request and creates a new instance of an observable?

Comment: The service http getter should almost always return an `Observable`. The component who needs this http response should call this service's method and do whatever it needs inside its `subscribe` callback.

Comment: One thing to consider is that with AngularFire2 it's not the actual instances that consume resources; each instance is very light weight. It's the subscriptions that consume resources. Each subscription has an internal Firebase ref, so having two instances each with one subscription is essentially no different to one instance with two subscriptions.

Comment: @cartant - So calling `getData(){return this.af.database.object("users/"+auth.uid+"/public")}` doesn't make two network requests to the database if called from different components? The second dilemma I have to deal with here is that I can only call `getData()` if the `auth.uid` exists, and the only way I know to get that is to Subscribe to `this.af.auth` - which means when the auth state changes it re-runs all subscriptions which in turn boops out more observables - just seems messy in my head.

Comment: Observables returned by the `list` and `object` methods will make a network connection with each subscription. Subscriptions to the `auth` observable are different. It listens behind the scenes via a single call to [`onAuthStateChanged`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onAuthStateChanged) and is implemented using a [`ReplaySubject`](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/2.0.0-beta.8/src/auth/auth.ts#L29), so it only ever involves a single, shared connection, so to speak, regardless of the number of subscribers.

Comment: That's a bit of a simplification, as there is will be sharing going on in the Firebase client, but the implication is that creating multiple `list` observables for the same database path won't be any different to having multiple subscriptions to a single `list` observable.

Comment: The problem I have is that if in my component I have this `data = this.dataService.getData.subscribe(data => return data)` then when I log out the `getData` function is called again (because it subscribes to `this.af.auth`) and throws an error because `auth.uid` does not exist. I can easily check if it does exist, however I can't return false or null because it's an invalid subscription type. Whats the solution here?